# Multilevel XML ForEach WPF

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, foreach

I need to get the values from many nodes in a XML that is a few levels deep.

Valid XML Sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <server>
  <id>245723</id>
  <name>Server Name</name>
  <host>IP Address</host>
  <port>Port</port>
   <servertype>
    <type>Linux</type>
    <cpu>Linux</cpu>
     <connections>
       <connection>
         <id>1234</id>
         <con_type>new</con_type> 
       </connection>
       <connection>
         <id>565665</id>
         <con_type>new</con_type> 
       </connection>
       <connection>
         <id>908546546466</id>
         <con_type>old</con_type> 
       </connection>
     </connections>
    </servertype>
   </server>
```

So basically I need to access and run through a `foreach` inside the connections node. I have used the below code to get the first level nodes values (each node) into a `listbox`. Works well.

C# Code for reading XML

```
string urlAddress = "url to xml file on server";
XDocument itemz = XDocument.Load(urlAddress);

foreach (var item in itemz.Descendants("server"))
{
    string name = item.Element("id").Value;

    //adding value to a listbox (sample)
    lstBox.Items.Add(txtBoxName.Content = item.Element("id").Value);
}
```

Is there a way to use the same code(as such) to get each item(value) under the connections nodes. So something like flow example below

```
  server> servertype > connections > foreach connection > get values of connection
```

would it require something like

```
foreach (var item in itemz.Descendants("server")) {

    foreach (var item in itemz.Descendants("connections"))  {

        //foreach connection
        foreach (var item in itemz.Descendants("connection")) {

            //add connection id to listbox 
            lstBox.Items.Add(txtBoxName.Content = item.Element("id").Value);
        }
    }
}
```

**********Edit**********

Using the below code to fetch multiple values to listbox output

```
//foreach connection inside connections

//connection node inner node values
string id = item.Element("id").Value);
string type = item.Element("type").Value);
string other = item.Element("other").Value);
string etc = item.Element("etc").Value);

lstBox.Items.Add(txtBoxName.Content = id + type + other + etc;
```

Comment: Could you be clearer about your expected output. Your last example would simply put all "id" element values that belong to a "connection" node into a list. Is that what you want to achieve? Or do you have a list per server? Or ... something else?

Comment: Basically under the connections node there are multiple connection nodes with nodes (id, type etc) inside them with the values that im trying to output into a list box for each connection node..Edited question with how want to add each item to the listbox

Comment: @Alex suggestion worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add all "id" element values for all "connection" nodes to your `lstBox`, you can simply do this:

```
XDocument itemz = XDocument.Load(urlAddress);

// ...

foreach (var item in itemz.Descendants("connection"))
    lstBox.Items.Add(txtBoxName.Content = item.Element("id").Value);
```

There is no need to traverse the hierarchy yourself, that is what `Descendants` will do for you.

Although the `txtBoxName.Content = ...` is a funny construction, of which the purpose is not clear to me. Why would you be setting this repeatedly, instead of using the last item added to set as its content.